# OpenJDK 15 and Docker

Tags: java, docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to get Docker running with JDK 15 I am following https://github.com/markhobson/docker-maven-chrome/blob/master/jdk-15/Dockerfile but I get `ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder165793576/google-chrome.repo: no such file or directory`

My Docker file is:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

## Google Chrome
ARG CHROME_VERSION=87.0.4280.88-1
ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

# ChromeDriver

ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=87.0.4280.88
RUN microdnf install -y unzip \
    && curl -s -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && mv /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && chmod 755 /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && ln -s /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver

###

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Does anyone know how to fix? I do not have a file `google-chrome.repo` - does anyone know the best way to get that?

Comment: Do you have a file *google-chrome.repo* on your host next to your *Dockerfile*? If not, this is your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with the following Docker File:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-15

# Google Chrome

ARG CHROME_VERSION=87.0.4280.88-1
ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

## ChromeDriver

ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=87.0.4280.88
RUN microdnf install -y unzip \
    && curl -s -o /tmp/chromedriver.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip \
    && unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt \
    && rm /tmp/chromedriver.zip \
    && mv /opt/chromedriver /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && chmod 755 /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION \
    && ln -s /opt/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

where google-chrome.repo is:

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```